# imagesLoaded.JS Mozilla not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [imagesLoaded.js](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) to wait for images before firing some evetns. It works great in Chrome and Safari but not in Firefox. Here is the code:

```
$('#consumer-bg, #page').imagesLoaded({ background: true })

  //Place anything you want to run after images in here
  .done( function( instance ) {

      //remove Preloader
      TweenLite.to($('#preloader'), 1, {autoAlpha: 0 });

      //load menu
      menu(1000);

      //Run home animation 
      homeAnimation(1500);

      //how step animation
      howSteps();

      charitySteps();

   });
```

If I take my functions out of the `.imagesLoaded` the site loads fine. When they are in it, the preloader and other functions never fire.

Any ideas??

Comment: https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded/issues/191

Comment: There is a fork of imagesLoaded that should work in firefox:  https://github.com/hi-impact/imagesloaded/tree/fix-issue-191  You won't be able to use this fork in NPM, you'll have to download it off the link and add imagesloaded.pkgd.js (or the minified version) to your site yourself.

You can link that into a node project though with gulp-concat, gulp-minify, etc etc.

Comment: This fix will introduce a new issue though, where the height of images might not resize properly if your images need resized with css etc.

Comment: This fix just break is in all browsers with the error from the plugin: `EventEmitter is not a constructor`

Comment: I have figure out that it only breaks in firefox when I pass two selectors in `(#consumer-bg, #page)`. If I just use one it works, but I want to check for all the images in `#page` and the background image in `#consumer-bg`. When all those are loaded, then fire the functions. Is there another way of doing this??

Comment: Did u find a solution? I have the same problem in Firefox